# Access Google Cloud Storage by AWS S3 SDK met 403 error for files with special character

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-storage

I'm using AWS S3 SDK to access Google Cloud Storage files. It works fine for normal files. But for those files with special characters like '(', ':', it would fail for 403 forbidden errors. Is there a way to make it work?

Here are a code snippet that can repro the issue:

```
                var getMetadataRequest = new GetObjectMetadataRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = "testbucket",
                    Key = "4(5).txt"
                };
                var response = await s3Client.GetObjectMetadataAsync(getMetadataRequest);
```

Comment: To break this issue down, have you tried accessing your objects via gcloud? This will allow you to determine if the issue is with GCS or with the AWS S3 SDK.

Comment: Thanks @maniSidhu98. I think the issue should be more like in AWS S3 SDK. However, as GCS supports S3 compatible APIs, so I'm more wondering about whether it is a known limitation on S3 compatible API or there is a way to workaround that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

I found a way to fix the above error by using the V2 signature version. However, I'm not sure whether this is an official fix, and it seems no such knowledge in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating).

```
            var config = new AmazonS3Config()
            {
                ServiceURL = @"https://storage.googleapis.com",
                SignatureVersion = "2"                 // this is the trick!!!
            };
```